# Calculate miles base latitude two cities

Tags: php, mysql, google-maps, latitude-longitude, google-latitude

I wrote a function calculate distance between city base https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlsearch_v3?csw=1

Austin, TX 78723: lat:30.282911 long:-97.712541

Austin, TX 78730: lat:30.3732514 long: -97.8395151

```
insert 78730 into market and run sql:
SELECT *, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(30.305107) ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians(-97.686631) ) + sin( radians(30.305107) ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM markers ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 20;

return 9.8 mile
```

but in site http://maps.randmcnally.com/?s=screen&loc1=Austin%2C%20TX%2078723&loc2=Austin%2C%20TX%2078730#s=screen&lat=39.11339950561523&lon=-94.62660217285156&zoom=9&loc1=Austin%2C%20TX%2078723&loc2=Austin%2C%20TX%2078730&loc3=&loc4=&loc5=&loc6=&loc7=&loc8=&loc9=&loc10=
return 18 mile

google map: 19.2 mile

What the number is correct?

Comment: According to [this](http://www8.nau.edu/cvm/latlongdist.html) the answer is 9.8242 statute miles, but it comes with the caveat: `This calculation assumes the earth is a perfect sphere
with a radius of 3963.1 statute miles`. The others may be making [different assumptions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth_radius).

Answer (score 1):

What you calculate is the distance as the crow flies, both(google maps and the other service) calculate the distances based on a route(e.g. driving).

The geometry-library of the google-maps-javascript-API also calculates 9.8 miles, so you may assume that your calculation is correct, but you calculate a completely different thing.

The different results of the 2 services may be based on different routes or different algorithms

Comment: +1 . . . Well, not quite as the "crow flies".  That would increase the radius by some amount.  More as super-earthworm crawls with no deviation?

Comment: OK, as the crow walks ;)

Comment: I want calculate distance by car or bus route. Is there any algorithms to slove?

Comment: If you want to calculate driving distances, you either need a database of routes, and traverse the directed graph, or you need to use an API for an existing service, like Bing or Google maps.